# removeEventListener from a function, not working, tried everything (I think)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, event-listener

I really have tried my hardest on this little problem, its been 2 weeks of long evenings and I know one of you more experienced AS3 developer would fix in a minute or two, well I hope.

So I have a very simple game with drag able objects that you let go of with MOUSEUP an animation plays then hits the subject and makes another animation (splat or something). With the hitTest only on one frame from inside the movie clip. (this works fine)

I am having problems removing said eventListener, I tried removing it at the end of the animation, so on the last from on the animation there would be AS saying removeEventListener from stage, but this didn't work, so I tried removeEventListener after dynamically added the animation to the stage, still no joy.

I hoped it was something simple like- this.removeEventListener or currentTarget, but alas no.

I really can't think of anything else,

for the love of AS please help. 
An explanation would also be amazing I understand how people don't have time so really any input would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my AS, if anyone wants to see the FLA, I can send it on, I am cool with sharing.

NB its probably quite evident I am a novice so please help me on my way....

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

import flash.events.*;

var test:dart = new dart();
addChild(test);
circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag);

function fl_ClickToDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    circle.startDrag();
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop);

function fl_ReleaseToDrop(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    circle.stopDrag();
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkIfHitTest);
    function checkIfHitTest(Event)
    {

        if (circle.hitTestObject(square))
        {
            trace("true, the circle and square are colliding");
            var s:blood_splat = new blood_splat();
            addChild(s);
            s.x = mouseX;
            s.y = mouseY;
            **removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkIfHitTest);**

        }
        else
        {
            trace("false, the circle and square are not colliding");
            var s:blood_splat = new blood_splat();
            addChild(s);
            s.x = mouseX;
            s.y = mouseY;
            s.alpha = 0.1;
            **removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkIfHitTest);**
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Just a bit of ancillary advice, I believe Amy is on the right track below.  Another bit of advice, in OOP languages it's conventional to use upper case to start Class names and camelCase to define variable instances.  So for example var test:Dart = new Dart(); this makes it more readable and obvious when a class is being used versus the instance of an object.  Also look into the Document Class for Flash CSXX this way you can encapsulate this code and have clearer scopes instead of just laying code into the timeline.Also You've never tried everything there's an infinite amount of indirection :)

Comment: One more piece of generic coding advice, use longer variable names, we have the advantage of tab-completion in most decent IDEs and it's better to be more explicit in your code and make it readable than needing to have comments to explain it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will try and start getting my AS in classes it seems like a nice and organised way, I get a little confused with the private, public and static classes and trying to reach movie clips inside movie clips inside containers on the stage, I have only been doing this for 5-6 weeks and I am constantly feeling out of my depth. Your right about trying everything, I should have said "I have tried everything that I know and hoped someone clever could help".

Comment: @user16237 yah was just being a stickler on that one, and saying you could always go further out of your way to get to a destination, it's just an interesting thing in programming, the infinite continuum of nature expressed in something we commonly think of as being discrete or purely binary (more philosophical than pragmatic).   In terms of scopes and modifiers and the language in general this reference is the best I've found http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f31.html still it lacks design patterns and other practical uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do:

```
Event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.type, checkIfHitTest)
```

Comment: It's likely that at the point they're calling removeEventListener, this is referring to the function, fl_ReleaseToDrop.

Comment: Hi mgraph,Thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately it gave me a error saying

Comment: ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property ENTER_FRAME not found on flash.events.Event and there is no default value.
 at MethodInfo-8()

Comment: MY GOD< YOUR AMAZING, its got it, ahhhhhh you have saved me a whole night of scratching my head, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try defining checkIfHitTest outside of fl_ReleaseToDrop.  In theory, what you did should work, since your removeEventListener code is also running within the closure of fl_ReleaseToDrop, but it is possible that its definition is being ignored, since you're not supposed to define named functions inside other functions like that.

Another possible issue is that you're giving the argument to checkIfHitTest the same name as the Class, Event, so you have conflicting definitions--your event instance doesn't have a constance ENTER_FRAME.

Honestly, even though you clearly have strict mode off, or you'd be seeing a ton of compile errors, I can't imagine that you're not getting runtime errors. Do you have the debug player installed? You really should turn strict typing back on--it would give you the feedback to at least start to resolve a lot of these issues on your own.

Comment: Thanks very much for your advice Amy I will attempt to place hitTest outside. Not completely sure how to do this but I am sure I can figure it out eventually. I will be putting strict mode on and try a debug, I didn't know it was off to be honest, i assume its off by default.